# Copying Attribute Data Attached To Column As Another Column

Tags: r, attributes, package, attr

I have a data set with each column having an attribute storing data. Meaning, columns has row wise values and then attributes to columns also have a value.

I can read the data attached to the column as attribute using `attr()`. However, my goal is to capture these attribute values and replicate as a columns.

**Reading Attribute**

```
> attr(data$`column1`, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber1
"6200"
> attr(data$`column2`, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber2
"7200"
```

**Input Data**

```
column1 column2
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
 -0.01   0.05
```

Then using above code, I want to append the values as shown below.

**Output Data**

```
column1 SomeNumber1 column2 SomeNumber2
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
 -0.01    6200        0.05     7200
```

How can I implement this recursively for data with more than 1000 columns? Each read will require call to `attr()` with unique column name to capture the attribute data and then replicate it as another adjust column.

I am getting confused on how I can recursively do this and that too in an optimized way.

Please share suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't provide an reproducible example. so I created one and hope it fits your problem:

```
column1 = rep(-0.01, 8)
attr(column1, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber1 = "6200"
column2 = rep(0.05, 8)
attr(column2, "metadata")$DP.SomeNumber2 = "7200"

data = data.frame(column1, column2)
```

Using lapply you can iterate over the columns of your dataframe. For each column the attributes were added as a new column to the original dataframe. Here is the code of my solution:

```
# create function to extract attributes of a given column(name) an create new column in original dataframe
attr2col <- function(col) {
  myAttr = attr(data[,col], "metadata")
  data[,sub("^DP\\.", "", names(myAttr))] <<- myAttr[[names(myAttr)]]
}

# iterate over colums of original dataframe
lapply(names(data), attr2col)
```

Comment: .@MarkusN - Thanks. What's `col` in `function(col)`. It has to be passed from `attr2col()`, if I am correct?

Comment: @Chetan Arvind Patil - It's actually the columnname, that is passed in lapply. Long form would be lapply(names(data), function(x) attr2col(x)).

Comment: .@MarkusN - I get `Error: subscript out of bounds` for `myAttr[[names(myData)]]`. In `myAttr`, I do get all the required attributes. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Chetan Arvind Patil - I assumed a data structure that meets your problem. apparently your data seems to be different, maybe you have to provide an example of your data.