# Why does "dim" not work as name for an attribute and how can I make it work?

Tags: r

I got an error and after some search I realized, that the "name of a character" causes the problem.
However, I still don't understand how a character can be transferred to a function and I don't know how to solve it.
The best I got is the name with extra "" - see below.
(I could use other hacks like "mydim" everywhere, but that is not what I am looking for.)

**So how can I make the following really work without an error?**

```
a <- 5
special <- list(mydim = c(100L, 9L),
                mydimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("3", "4", "5")))
names(special)[[1]]
# [1] "mydim"
special[[1]]
# [1] 100   9
attr(x = a, which = names(special)[[1]]) <- special[[1]]
attributes(a)
# $hurz
# [1] "hurz"
# $mydim
# [1] 100   9

special2 <- list(dim = c(100L, 9L),
                 dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("3", "4", "5")))
names(special2)[[1]]
# [1] "dim" # ............................ of class character only!!
special2[[1]]
# [1] 100   9

# The following commands all result in the same error:
attr(x = a, which = as.character(names(special2)[[1]])) <- special2[[1]]
# Error in attr(x = a, which = names(special2)[[1]]) <- special2[[1]] : 
#   dims [product 900] do not match the length of object [1]

# The best I got with extra '':
attr(x = a, which = deparse(names(special2)[[1]])) <- special2[[1]]
attributes(a)
# $hurz
# [1] "hurz"
# $mydim
# [1] 100   9
# $`"dim"`
# [1] 100   9
```

For the error message in general see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317124/5784831).
It seems although "dim" is a charcater, it uses dim() and calculates 9*100 = 900...

Comment: This is documented in `?attr`.  The attribute names "class, comment, dim, dimnames, names, row.names and tsp) are treated specially and have restrictions on the values which can be set."

Comment: Note that a `matrix` naturally has an attribute named `dim` (and perhaps `dimnames`), likely why (among many classes) `attr` has that restriction.

Comment: @user2554330 Do you have a solution? the "values" are fine - just the name is changed. To me the documentation is misleading in this case(?)

Comment: I don't see what you find to be misleading.  Where was the name changed?

Comment: @user2554330 OK I understand, it is not that the chacrater is changed but a restriction is put on attribute-names. So what I wanted (my personal "dim" attribute is not possible?

Comment: Right, it would only be allowed if it obeyed the same rules as the standard one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is much simpler than you make out.  The problem isn't "the name of a character"; the problem is the attribute name you have chosen.  As documented in `?attr`,

> Note that some attributes (namely class, comment, dim, dimnames,
> names, row.names and tsp) are treated specially and have restrictions
> on the values which can be set. (Note that this is not true of levels
> which should be set for factors via the levels replacement function.)

You are trying to set the `"dim"` attribute of `a`, and the rule is that it needs to be a numeric vector whose product is the length of `a`.  The reason for this rule is that `"dim"` is used by R internal functions, and if you were allowed to put something else there, they would need a lot more error checking, so would be a lot slower.

So your `"mydim"` solution is really the only way to go.